# Can data science be applied to establishing the author of a text?

Tags: data-mining

There are many instances of quotes and texts where the true author may be disputed. Are there data science or machine learning techniques which may be useful to establish the authorship?

Comment: You can. This data mining competition has included in the past author identification contests and the results were very good: http://pan.webis.de/clef16/pan16-web/author-identification.html. You use things like topics, the adverbs they use, etc. They have published papers on the best performing models.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is an active area of study, especially famously with respect to disputed plays of Shakespeare. Features commonly extracted include frequency of key words, novel vocabularly, word length, and these are well adapted to being used as data mining features.

For example, here is a thesis that data mined Shakespeare's extant plays to test whether they could have been the work of a number of authors often touted as being the "true Shakespeare" -> http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~datamining/Final.pdf

Comment: How long did it take you to find the answer to the question you yourself asked?

Comment: The question kind of came second - I wrote the answer for a question that was kind off topic and then realised it didn't answer that question at all, but I still thought it was interesting, so I wrote the question around the answer, kind of like Jeopardy.